# Germany ATMs with magstripe

Tags: germany, payment-cards, atms

I will be traveling to Germany shortly. I have a credit card with a chip, but my debit card only has a magstripe. Do any foreign ATM still accept magstripe cards or will I be forced to rely on my credit card for all purchases?

Comment: Related (but not a dupe IMHO): [using credit cards in Germany](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/920/32134) but be aware most answers are from 2011

Comment: As of summer 2015, _every_ bank ATM I encountered in Europe accepted magstripe cards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only went to a small number of ATMs, but had no issue using my American magstripe cards on them.

Comment: Ditto. The only places where I've had issues with magstripe-only cards are some automated vending machines, such as train or bus ticket machines. Never had an ATM demand a chip card so far.

Comment: Talked to my bank last night. Pretty sure my card got skimmed at one of the ATMs...