# Will we be required to use a PIN associated with our credit cards in Central Europe?

Tags: germany, payment-cards, austria, czech-republic

We are headed to Austria, Germany and the Czech Republic in a couple of weeks and heard we may be required to use a PIN along with our credit cards. Is this true?  I don't even know what my PIN is!

Comment: Certainly so for cash withdrawals at ATMs. For regular payments the signature is will do.

Comment: Does your card even have a chip?

Comment: You can call your bank to get your PIN set up

Comment: In what country are your cards issued?

Comment: Anything with a cashier won't be a problem but ticket machines and similar might refuse your card. Be prepared though that not every store accepts credit cards but it's much better than it was before.

Comment: @Aganju It's no problem to get a German-issued credit card which uses signature instead of PIN.

Comment: @neo but you'd still need a PIN to withdraw money from an ATM. Related Q (watch out, some answers are old): [Are there any issues with using credit cards in Germany?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/920/32134)

Comment: @Aganju Can we have less of the USA-bashing please, there are plenty of examples where security trumps convenience in the US. There are also many countries that have not implemented chip and pin.

Comment: Credit card or debit card? The title says credit cards but the answers seem to be about debit cards...

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas In many countries, from the merchant's perspective, there is no difference, as long as the card is on one of their supported networks. The merchant may pay a higher interchange fee, but that is not something she will be advised of at time of the transaction.

Comment: @Calchas: "The merchant may pay a higher interchange fee" - wouldn't it rather be the *customer* who pays that fee at least in some stores? At least when ordering something online, you very often have to pay extra fees when paying by credit card; couldn't some stores act the same way?

Comment: Where are you from? A bank in which country issued your cards?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper such a fee is virtually unknown in the US.

Answer (score 21):

I work in the industry and therefore feel qualified to answer this question.

For cards bearing a chip; if you need to use a PIN in your home country, then you will be required to use a PIN overseas. The preferred method of authorisation is embedded into the chip in your card. All terminals that comply to the EMV standard will request a PIN to authenticate the transaction if the card is configured as 'Chip & PIN'.

If your card is configured for 'Chip & Signature', then a PIN will not be required.

The only exceptions are in the US (and a limited number of other countries) where a proportion of retailers have still not implemented EMV terminals at their Point of Sale.  In these cases, EMV chip & PIN cardholders are required to swipe and sign, and more often than not, are requested to show photo ID.

If your card does not have a chip, then no PIN will be required anywhere worldwide.  However, you may find that your card is simply not accepted or that the terminal or machine is unable to process it.

One note for Germany in particular, credit cards are not as widely accepted as in other European countries.  Debit cards can be used almost everywhere, but you may want to plan on carrying enough cash to cover in case you find yourself in a place where you cannot use credit cards.

As mentioned in the comments to the question - vending machines in the countries you are planning to visit, as well as public transport ticketing machines will only accept EMV chip and pin cards and frequently, only EMV debit cards are accepted.  In some cases, a ticket machine may be the only way to purchase a ticket and you may need to ask the assistance of a local to buy a ticket on your behalf.

Comment: Photo ID? I use my UK-issued chip and pin cards in many countries abroad, in places where a signature is often required. Usually the merchants don't even look at the signature—they give the card back before asking you to sign a receipt. I am only bringing up my own experience here but no one has ever asked me for photo ID for a signature-authorized transaction, even when that transaction runs into hundreds of US dollars.

Comment: "The preferred method of authorisation is embedded into the chip in your card" Not necessarily. Not every terminal supports every cardholder verification method. In particular, many German cards only support online-verified PIN which most (e.g.) UK and French terminals don't support so they fall back to signature.

Comment: @Calchas In Sweden you are often asked for ID if you have a signature-preferring card. And they have fully implemented EMV.

Comment: This is more for the US, where credit card fraud is widespread and malls are located out of town on major highways and are frequent targets for petty criminals with stolen or cloned cards.

Comment: @neo I can point you to the EMV specification documents that show that the preferred method is embedded.  The terminal has the right to refuse anything other than Chip & PIN, but in such cases, the correct protocol is to refuse the card rather than request the PIN.

Comment: @PassKit The details are a bit to long for this comment section (I will prepare a question and answer here shortly) but having cards not supporting embedded PIN verification and terminals not supporting online PIN verification and falling back to signature (if the card is configured as such) is fully compliant and a well-known phenomenon with many German cards used abroad.

Comment: For sure it is possible, if the fallback method is configured in the card AND such method is acceptable to the terminal (which is a proxy for the merchant acquirer).  To be fair, the Germans are better than most at implementing the EMV spec and catering for overseas cards with less stringent authorisation requirements.

Comment: @Calchas I've been living in Germany for two years now and use my German debit card daily. In my case, around 50% of the payments are with signature and so far, I've signed a receipt without being asked for ID exactly 6 times.

Comment: @AndrejaKo: May I ask for some examples of stores where you were asked for your ID card? I'm wondering because I live in Germany, I pay almost all of my groceries in supermarkets and many other things by debit cards (various, from several banks), and in my whole life, I have never been asked for an ID card.

Comment: Before chip cards were common, UK cards supported Swipe & PIN; I assume this is still in the standard, and part of the fall-back if the chip can't be read.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper Let's see what comes to mind: All Rewes that use signature (some Rewes use pin and they don't ask for IDs), Sky when paying with signature (sometimes ask for IDs with PIN, but it's usually before POS terminal indicates it wants PIN), Penny, Bauhaus I think... I can't remember of any other at the moment. I also use Edeka and Aldi, but they only use PIN, so they don't ask for ID cards. I've only been to Lidl once so I don't remember how it went and I've never been to Famila, so I don't know what they use.

Comment: @AndrejaKo: Interesting. Must be your card or something else semi-specific to you then. I live very close to a Rewe market and therefore have been buying stuff there every week during the past few years, and while I am randomly asked for a PIN or a signature for any given card I pay with (it's like that in all stores, as far as I can tell, with all debit cards that I've used), I have never been asked for an ID.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper That could very well be the case.  My card comes from Deutsche Bank's "Das Junge Konto" package and I've also seen other students with the came card type being asked for their IDs as well, so it might be card-specific.

Comment: @CSM when would swipe-and-pin have been used? I have never used it (outside of ATMs), it was always swipe-and-signature before the switchover for every transaction I ever did in the UK since I got my first card.

Comment: @AndrejaKo But both Germany and Sweden have implemented chip and pin. My comment was in reply to the assertion that countries which have not implemented chip and pin "more often than not" require ID to authenticate transactions. It may be true. But it is not my experience.

Comment: @CSM "Before chip cards were common, UK cards supported Swipe & PIN" ATMs in the UK used magstripe and PIN in the pre-chip era (and probablly still do for non-chip cards), but I never heard of swipe and pin at UK point of sale, it was always either swipe and sign or chip and pin. Many retailers did use a system that swiped into a chip reader though (so it could process both swipe and sign and chip and pin transactions without the cashier having to do anything different).

Answer (score 5):

I have used a US debit card in Czech Republic couple of years ago. I had to enter PIN to withdraw from ATM, but for paying in shops, a signature was required instead. I believe this is related to the fact that the card didn't have a chip (like my Czech debit card does), only a magnetic strip.

The other kind of cards I have experience with are Czech debit cards. With new ones, they not only have a chip, but are also contactless, which means you don't have to enter PIN (or write signature) if you're paying less than 500 CZK.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your card capabilities. If it is EMV compliant with a chip then it may happen very probably across all Europe.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend only having a magstripe & signature card in Europe as, in some places, the card reader won't accept magstripe or the magstripe reader is covered. Chip and Signature will work in a lot of places that accept the card. Keep in mind, though, that in some countries VISA and MasterCard acceptance is poor and AmEx even worse. In the Netherlands, for example, Maestro and V-Pay are dominant (a European standard) or, in Germany, some places only accept the national standard girocard. Although slowly it's changing, if you shop in the big chains, you probably won't have a problem.

And, as others said, some credit card readers may require a PIN to work. The German Railway, for example, recently changed its ticket machines to prompt for a PIN, as customers have raised security concerns.

In some countries contactless payments are getting more and more popular (Especially in eastern Europe, where in some countries it's an exception not to be able to pay contactless, but sometimes also in Germany, UK etc.). This means you can easily get along with Apple- and AndroidPay. You may consider setting it up for your card and use your Phone for payments whenever you see the contactless logo to avoid complications.

Comment: Until recently, nearly all US-issued cards were stripe/signature cards.  Then the card issuers started sending out chip/signature cards (that have a stripe as well).  The issuers don't generally give the customer a choice; you have to find a different issuer if you want a different kind of card (there are a handful that issue chip/pin cards, who mostly sell to the international business traveler market).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are American, your credit card (and maybe your ATM/Debit card) will either be a chip & signature card or and older-style swipe and signature card.

For ATM cash withdrawals, your ATM card + PIN will almost certainly work fine. You may be able to use a credit card for cash advances this way as well; contact your credit card company for the PIN. Note that fees for withdrawals with your ATM card will be substantially lower than for with your credit card. This is your most reliable means of payment (many merchants do not accept credit cards), so I HIGHLY recommend you keep some cash handy at all times.

For chip+signature cards, you will be able to pay just fine for merchants with manned terminals, with no PIN required. Sometimes merchants will not know they need to ask for your signature, but I've never had a problem with the charge going through anyway. You will NOT be able to pay at automated kiosks, such as many autoroute toll booths in Austria and train/mass transit ticket machines. You MUST have cash on hand to pay at these machines.

For swipe and signature cards, you will likely be successful at higher end or more touristic restaurants and also at most hotels, but I wouldn't count on the card being usable most other places.

Source: American living in Europe and using both US and Euro cards extensively in Austria and Germany.