# Using Visa credit card in Denmark, Germany, Iceland

Tags: germany, money, payment-cards, iceland, denmark

I never use cash in the United States, paying for everything large and small with a credit card (they are universally accepted without fees for practically all purchases). Can I expect the same as a tourist in Denmark, Germany, and Iceland? How common is credit card use? Do all establishments accept  Visa "chip and PIN" credit cards or do I need to carry the local currency in these countries for coffee shops, restaurants, attractions, shopping, transport, etc.? I'm concerned because I'm only in each country for a few days and all the use different currency. I've no need for ISK, DNK, or Euro currency after my trip, so using a card would be much easier.

Comment: You should always have _some_ cash on hand. Even in the US. If yours isn't one of the rare banks that gave you an actual Chip and PIN card, rather than Chip and Signature, you should hunt one down before you go.

Comment: For Germany, see: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/920/16436

Comment: German shops universally accept cards, but sometimes only local debit card and not credit cards (or necessarily all foreign debit card). You will therefore need some cash as a back up. Don't know about Iceland at all, don't recall any trouble in Denmark but I haven't been there a lot.

Comment: Tip for Germany: know the German equivalent of your credit card so they can identify it when you show it to them . "Eurocard" being  a prime example

Comment: It would be better to ask questions about each country individually (you can see that the answers here are all only partial). I think most of these have already been asked in fact.

Comment: @CMaster I agree. Voting to close as too broad. Ask individually.

Comment: @GayotFow tip for Germany: use a Visa or MasterCard, because everything else is accepted in much less places. They are then called "Visa" and "MasterCard" in Germany

Comment: Credit/usa is a horrible conceit that makes perfect sense after you bother adding up all the transaction fees, as is debit/canada

Comment: @GayotFow Eurocard hasn't been a thing for more than a decade now and card schemes have the same name in Germany now as everywhere else.

Comment: @neo, right but not all Germans know this

Comment: @GayotFow I will pay a finder's fee for a store employee that "knows" that they accept Eurocard and refuses to take a MasterCard.

Comment: @neo I explain it every time I'm in Germany, but I'm grateful for your assurance and certainty and will keep your comments in mind next time.

Comment: Editing the question for clarity about reasons doesn't change the fact that this isn't a good question. Ask about each country separately.

Answer (score 9):

Major shops, hotels, etc. in Germany will accept credit cards like Visa or MasterCard. Smaller ones might not. So if you want an ice cream on a hot day, you may need cash.

Some smaller shops accept card payment only above a certain limit, e.g. € 10.

Comment: To make sure no one contradicts you "from [his] own experience last year", you should add that [discounters like ALDI started accepting credit cards not too long ago](http://www.n24.de/n24/Wissen/Finanzen/d/6960138/hier-koennen-sie-mit-kreditkarte-zahlen.html).

Comment: You're right about the shops, but I think almost all hotels accept credit cards because a credit card can serve as a guarantee for a reservation.

Answer (score 6):

**Personal experience**
I have been in Iceland, Denmark as well as Germany and usually pay with a mix of cash, bank card and credit card.
I do not remember ever having been asked to pay in a different way in any of the countries unless there was a fault in the connection with their bank.

**Iceland**
Iceland has card payments on almost everything, even the hotdog stand at the harbour and the smallest shops and coffee corners. But not all of Iceland has easy access to telephone connections and in those cases cards will not work.
Specially if you go off the [#1 road](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Route_1_(Iceland)), there may be problems with card acceptance.
Here it depends on location, if you stay in Reykjavic and the areas that are covered by short tours from there, you will likely be OK without cash.

**Denmark**
Denmark used to be less covered than Iceland when I was there last, but it might have more coverage now. In one of the other answers a local indicate that is can be 100% coverage now, at least as long as you select your locations.

**Germany**
Germany is less 100% covered in acceptance but more closely in telephone services, so it evens out. 
Most shops that deal with bigger amounts are happy to accept cards, but not all. In most towns and cities there will be ATM around the corner and even many villages have them, but you should still have some cash on you.

**Some cash**
I mostly try to keep one days worth of cash with me at all times, like enough for the last hotel bill, so I have enough for any restaurant if they do not accept cards or their machine fails.

**Which cards?**
In all three countries shops prefer debit cards on the local bank system, can be foreign cards as well, due to the lower costs. Credit cards do have higher fees for companies. Sometimes they will ask the customer to pay the fee, other times they just do not accept them.
This can result in only some cards being accepted, but those companies working for the tourist trade will mostly accept credit cards.
Supermarkets are more likely not to accept credit cards as are small restaurants mostly used by locals.
Cards on the Visa and the Mastercard system with chip and pin have a very wide acceptance, other credit cards and debit card systems are less known or not known at all.

**Cash or no cash at all?**
I personally would never travel without cash, I would get enough out for the last night hotel bill and keep that as money for when the cards do not work.

As you are less wanting to hold cash, are there only for a few days and are likely to visit places that tourists use, you can have less cash or evey dare to travel with on cash at all, but in that case you will have to ask every place you want to spend money whether they accept your card before you commit. So in a restaurant before you sit down.

**If you only carry one kind of money**
In all three countries they use their own money but if you have some euro left over after Germany, it is certain that the airport shops accept it instead of the local money, (also as a part payment and the rest on your card,) and it is more likely that smaller shops in town accept it rather than US dollars, and at a rate closer to the official exchange rate.
So if you take our advice to travel with some cash but do not want to carry all three, euros are the best bet.

Answer (score 4):

Most major Train stations (Hauptbahnhof) in Germany have an ATM to pick up Cash. The Fee will be between €2-5. A lot of shops in Germany accept credit cards but few accept a credit card that does not have an EMV Chip. I do recommend though keeping cash with you here in Germany.

I do not know anything about Iceland or Denmark.

Comment: I have never heard of an ATM that charges fees for Visa cards in Germany (though that's now allowed) and only very few charge for MasterCard and a free one is usually near. Note that ATMs universally charge a fee for *German* debit cards (if used out-of-network) but that shouldn't be relevant for an international traveller.

Comment: Pretty much every chain accepts non-EMV cards but don't expect staff to be trained on what to do with such a card.

Comment: I live in Germany as an American, and yes at the ATM at a train station you have to pay a fee to the ATM. it takes €2-5. And in a supermarket i have tried to pay with those cards but it didnt accept it. I don't know if that help but I have had a couple of problems with that.

Answer (score 4):

As a dane I haven't touched hard currency in years (except for when my grandma sends me a birthday card) and I'm not exaggerating here, nor am I a basement dweller that never leaves my house.

Card useage is close to 100 %. I've personally had more trouble in the US and other countries with stores not accepting cards than I've had here. Flea markets and "hobby stores" being the exception. (Farmer Bobs produce stand by the side of the road, Aunt Annes flowers that she sells out of her garage, etc.)

If you do find a store that doesn't accept card payments then you have to go hunting for an ATM as they're typically not inside stores like I've seen a lot of in the US. You have to find a bank (which in danish is called "bank" so that should be easy to spot in the cityscape). Some major stores may have an ATM inside, including shopping malls/major attractions like Tivoli.

In regards to card fees then that varies from store to store and from card to card.
By law stores are *permitted* to charge a fee for **CREDIT CARDS**, *not debit cards/debit transactions* ([Source in danish](https://www.danskebank.dk/da-dk/privat/kort/raadgivning/pages/kortgebyrer-butikker.aspx)). It is very unlikely though as the public *hates* those fees with a passion and there have been major uproars whenever some major chain said they wanted to introduce a transaction fee, which they have had to roll back because people boycotted them.

By law you can at most be charged the same fee that the store have to pay to the card providers for the transaction itself.

**Just make sure you have a 4 digit pin code for your card as most terminals doesn't accept signatures for authorization.** Signing transactions/cards without a pin-code are not a thing here (not talking about contactless payment, that is a thing here although less widespread).

Comment: Smaller independent shops away from tourist centres in Denmark are more likely to charge a fee for foreign credit cards (say 3-4.5%). Source: my receipts from last week.

Answer (score 3):

I've never been to Denmark or Germany, but in Iceland, the locals use credit cards almost exclusively. I don't think I went anywhere that did not accept my Visa card. (Nobody accepted Discover, one place did not accept MasterCard and since I have neither AmEx nor Diners Club I don't recall the acceptance rates of those networks.)

Of course, everyone also accepts cash for the most part, and since they do they'll have cash on hand to make change, etc. But generally it was only tourists I saw paying cash. Even stopping into a coffee shop for a drink was paid for by card.

Additionally not all of my cards are chipped, and the places I used them were able to handle them. To be safe I recommend carrying a chipped Visa or MasterCard since these are the most widely accepted networks in my experience.

Comment: I used my bank card instead of my credit card mostly, which was appreciated by the shops, as it has lower costs for them. My cards work on the Meastro system, so the MasterCard system, and they were accepted everywhere in Iceland. (Dutch cards, not USA.)

Comment: I've started seeing Maestro listed separately from MasterCard -- some places will accept my vanilla MC but not Maestro. Visa was universal though.

Comment: That is because Maestro is the debit (bank) card while MasterCard is the credit card. Visa has both under the same name and you may find that some places do not accept one kind of Visa.

Comment: The question is about credit cards, not debit/bank cards....

Answer (score 2):

General, non standard but useful european-wide payment tips i always give  to americans:

- Expect every non VISA or MASTERCARD credit or debit* card not
  accepted**.
- Expect every non PIN-based card not accepted***.
- Expect any purchase under 10€ in non-major or non-chained ( not fnac,
  MediaMarkt, starbucks, aldi, lidl, carrefour,mcdonalds, bking...)
  stores and restaurants not to be accepted by card.
- Expect VPT's (Vendor Point Terminals) to fail. always have backup
  cash.
- Do not expect a tip line or space in a credit or debit card ticket.
  tips, if accepted****, are in cash.

*Debit cards are not accepted in some toll speedways of france, belgium, and germany. just press "help" if you only have those, and they'll open the barrier for you.

**AmericanExpress,DinersClub,Etc... cards have a very low to non-existant card coverage in Europe.Here we like to standarise things, and things  overseas are non-standarizable. even if some places might accept them, it's better to not count on it at all.

***Pin-based accreditation ( or the newly standarized nfc/nfc+pin already working in most of europe's big stores ) is the most widely accepted form of payment. Magnet + signature is sometimes ( more often than it should be) not accepted, mostly because banks love to cut expenditure on VPT's, and most stores rent just-pin (or just-pin + nfc) VPT's nowadays.

****Tips, generally in europe, are small extra cash given for an extraordinary service ( or because customers hate smallchange), given either directly to the server with a "this is for your awesome service"-like comment, or in the cashier "for that super nice boy/girl that served us".  Tip lines on credit tickets are not only generally inexistant, there is 80% chances they can't do that in their Paying Terminal Software, because products have a stablished price so does the services offered, and extra cash entering could give tax problems, making the servers stay overtime counting every bill and every card payment ticket to find out "what client paid for an extra, un-annotated, unkown serving / plate / wine bottle ".